# Changing the Title of a product tab depending on the category

Tags: category, local.xml, tabs

I have added a new tab to my product page next to my description for PDF documents. I implemented this in the `local.xml` using

```
 <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
      <alias>pdf_tabbed</alias>
      <title>Data Sheets</title>
      <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
      <template>catalog/product/view/pdf.phtml</template>
 </action>
```

however i want to change the title depending on what category the product is in for example if you are in the clothing category (id:145) i want the Title to be "Sizing Guide" instead of "Data Sheets".

I have put an if statement in my `pdf.phtml` to display the sizing guide instead of the PDFs however i do not know how to change the Title. Is there any way to do this in either `local.xml` or to get it to get the title from `pdf.phtml`?

This is the code in my pdf.phtml

```
<?php $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();?>
<?php $_pdf = $this->getProduct()->getPdf(); ?>

<?php if ($currentCategoryId = '145')
{?> Size table code goes here } 

else{ 


<?php if ($_pdf): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('PDF') ?></h2>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_pdf, 'pdf') ?>
        <?php var_dump ($currentCategoryId);?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    Sorry but there are no data sheets associated with this product!
    <?php var_dump ($currentCategoryId);?>
<?php endif; 
};?>
```

summary: Is it possible to change the title of my tab depending on the category ID, either in the `local.xml` or the `.phtml` file it displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `action` tag in the layouts allow you to retrieve the parameters via a helper method.
Change your layout to look like this:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" >    
    <alias>pdf_tabbed</alias>
    <title helper="[module]/getTabName" />
    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
    <template>catalog/product/view/pdf.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Now you have to create a method called `getTabName` in one of the helpers of one of your modules (and replace `[module]` with the helper alias).

the method can look like this:

```
public function getTabName()
{
    $product = Mage::registry('product'); //get the current product
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds(); //get all the category ids associated to the product.
    //based on your custom logic that involves a category id you need to return a title
    if (some condition here) {
        return 'Your tab name here'; 
    }
    //if the product does not belong to a special category, return a default value
    return $this->__('Data Sheets');
}
```